# Bootloop, can't go to recovery, oem not unlocked

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot-loop, fastboot

I'll try to be straightforward. A couple of days back, I was using my phone and it got stuck, so I removed the battery as usual, and restarted it. It got restarted at that time, I plugged it in for whole night, and in morning it again stopped responding. I restarted it, and this time, it got bootloop. I opened recovery (It was accessible for first 2-3 trials), wiped cache, restarted and nothing happened. Its still on bootloop.  Now, I cant enter into recovery.

Device: Intex Aqua Turbo 4G, MTK 6375M, unrooted, oem locked, Debugging was turned on.

Things tried:

1. SP Flash tool: Download DA goes to 100%, then it shows BROM Error, code- 4008, or fax8 (different codes on different versions)
2. Fastboot: is accessible, device is detected on pc (using fastboot devices), but as OEM was not unlocked, cant flash)
3. Recovery, as stated is now unaccessible, all it shows is "Intex logo" on selecting recovery mode. Same goes for normal boot mode. Only fastboot works.

I can attach the BROM Error logs, if required. The memory tests of SP Flash tool goes fine, except that it writes NAND flash was not detected , and UFS was not detected. I dont know what this means. I can attach the scatter file too, (I thing that can be the culprit) if required.

Comment: Guess the downvote was due to your massive use of bold (I've fixed that in your post now). For starters: have you checked with our [boot-loop tag wiki](/tags/boot-loop/info) already?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks, I don't know how the Bolds got in first place. I've read the boot loop wiki, but as stated, the recovery cant be accessed, and I dint thing I can go into safe mode either, it was only possible if the device booted once, Ive not done it previously, if anyone could suggest a method, that would be great.

Comment: Always check the preview before submitting ;) The bolds got in by your `----` lines directly following a paragraph. If you wanted them to be horizontal rulers, make sure to have an empty line before and after. // Still not clear: did you try to get into safe mode – or did you not because you thought it won't work?

Comment: what is your question? do you want to recover userdata? do you want to factory reset?

Comment: Safe mode is unaccessible. I just want my phone turned on back, even if the userdata gets deleted. It just shows the intex logo as of now.